# Enviar e receber imagem via WebService

Tags: java, android, json, web-service, imagem

Estou desenvolvendo um app em que preciso converter uma imagem para JSON e enviar para um WebService. Posteriormente vou precisar realizar o caminho inverso, ou seja, receber uma imagem JSON de um WebService a apresenta-la ao usuário da aplicação.

Bom, para enviar a imagem estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
 byte[] imgByteArray = stream.toByteArray();

 String imgArray = Base64.encodeToString(imgByteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
 JSONObject jsonImg = new JSONObject().put("imgByteArray", imgArray);
```

Até ai, tudo ok.

Para receber a imagem estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
 JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseJSON);
 String imgBytes = responsegetString("imagem");

 byte[] imgRecebida = Base64.decode(imgBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
 Bitmap bitNew = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgRecebida, 0, imgRecebida.length);
```

Porém, a resposta que tenho no logcat é:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64
```

E se eu mudar Base64.decode para:

```
final byte[] imgRecebida = Base64.decode(imgBytes.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Recebo como resultado:

```
 D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

Alguém sabe o por que?

Comment: Ao que tudo indica, o problema está na forma como esses bytes estão sendo enviados para você. Tem como enviar essa string para um log, e encaminhá-la aqui, via [pastebin](http://pastebin.com), por exemplo?

Comment: Talvez este artigo lhe ajude com o crypt.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066762/illegalargumentexception-bad-base-64-while-trying-to-use-base64-on-android-1

Comment: Encontrei o erro. Ao receber a imagem no WebService estava salvando diretamente como byte[]. Quando retornava e tentava usar o factory ele não reconhecia aquele array de bytes ou dava erro no decode.
O que fiz foi salvar a imagem como string mesmo no servidor e depois devolve-la. Não sei se isso é a forma correta de fazer, mas deu certo. Se alguém tem uma solução melhor, avise-me, por favor.
Abraços.

Comment: Oi @AndreiMaxwel! Para encaminhar bytes crus de um lado ao outro usando JSON, você pode optar por utilizar a notação de array `[1, 123, 76 ... ]` ou utilizar a codificação base64. Com o base64 há um aumento de 33%, ou seja, 3 bytes viram 4 caracteres. Se você convertesse os bytes para a notação de array, o aumento seria muito maior, assim, não vale a pena, visto que o algoritmo do base64 é rápido. Agora, já que você mesmo encontrou a resposta, seria legal se você publicasse ela aqui, para que outras pessoas possam aprender também ;)

Comment: Olá Andrei, sobre a forma correta de armazenamento de imagens é a sua forma nativa mesmo, puro array de bytes. Salvar a imagem em uma string base64 tem suas vantagens e desvantagens, a vantagem é que você pode usá-la diretamente no html sem precisar fazer uma conversão, uma desvantagem é o alto consumo de armazenamento, tente também enviar esta imagem sobre a rede sem realizar conversão alguma, é mais rápido.

Answer (score 1):

O código apresentado esta certo, a unica diferença para o que usei a alguns tempos foi que em vez de 100 usava 50 ( `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);` ), por que não necessitava de muita qualidade. um bom teste seria pegar a string que esta no servidor e usar nesse site http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html.