# Como enviar e receber bitmap no servidor restful

Tags: android, servidor, bitmap, requisição

Pessoal dei uma pesquisada e achei bem pouco conteúdo, gostaria de umas dicas pois nunca fiz isso. Como eu envio e recebo um bitmap para um servidor? Mando com JSon? Converto para base64? Qual a melhor maneira de enviar e como deve ser meu método no servidor para receber? Valeu

Comment: Veja se ajuda você http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16374/android-enviar-e-receber-imagem-via-webservice

Comment: parece que ajuda muito, vou implementar oq ele fez e ver se funciona. Vle

Comment: Discordo em fechar como duplicata porque as respostas desta pergunta são bem melhores que a da outra.

Comment: Até o momento não havia respostas na pergunta, concordo contigo @VictorStafusa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Envie simplesmente como conteúdo binário.

```
String url = "http://seusite.com.br";
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath(),"suaImagem.jpg");
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
            new FileInputStream(file), -1);
    reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
    reqEntity.setChunked(true); // mande em pacotes separados se necessario
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (Exception e) {
    // Trate seu erro
}
```

Exemplo adaptado [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4126746/1845714).

Answer (score 4):

O correto é você codificar a imagem em base64 e enviar através do servidor, antes de enviar, converte a imagem com Base64 para um array de Byte e envia esse Objeto inteiro.

```
//Codificar uma imagem
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(),
                    R.drawable.imagem);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();
String encodedImage2 =Base64.encodeToString(bitMapData,Base64.DEFAULT);

//Decodificar
byte[] arquivo = null;
arquivo = Base64.decode(objeto.imagem.toString());
```

Comment: Opa blz, vi que ganha muito mais performance com Base64. Sabe como vou receber no servidor? Valeu pela ajuda

Comment: @roque na verdade você perde performance; conteúdo binário codificado em Base64 fica em torno de 37% maior.

Comment: O ideal seria eu passar uma string direto entao.

Comment: @roque Não há necessidade de realizar nenhuma transformação no conteúdo original; ele pode ser enviado como um array de bytes mesmo.